# Additional installation steps with npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I can't find this documented anywhere, but I'm working on a node package that will be installed via `npm install -g`.  This includes a binary and also several other sub packages that will be yeoman generators.  As far as I can tell, these also have to be installed via `npm install -g` (or `npm link`).  There doesn't seem to be any other way to use a generator.  If there is, it would be fine to point yeoman to one of the generators relative to this project too.

When my package is installed, I want all of the generators to be installed as well since my script will ultimately end up calling `yo one-of-my-generators`.

Is there anything I can do to make `npm install` of my project also install/link all of the generators it contains in one step?

Answer (score 0):

add them as peerDependencies in your package.json file. See the blog at http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/

Its also how we install things like mocha

Comment: Is it possible to specify a file relative to the project as a peer dependency?  I think that would work for what I need

Comment: If they really are modules, then they should be published somewhere like npm or git so files wouldn't be peer dependencies. If the file is part of the code then do a require like normal.

Comment: They need to be installed globally because they are Yeoman generators and from what I can tell you can only use globally installed Yeoman generators

Comment: Right, but you don't `require` them relative to your generator's directory. You `invoke` them or use `composeWith` like https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/app/index.js#L87-L97

Comment: The main package itself is *not* a generator